# How to use VueJS 2 global components inside single file components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to use a globally registered component (with *Vue.component*) inside a single file component but I am always getting

```
vue.common.js:2611[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <my-component> - did you register the component correctly?
```

For example:

main.js:

```
...
Vue.component('my-component', {
    name: 'my-component',
    template: '<div>A custom component!</div>'
})
...
```

home.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <my-component></my-component>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    module.exports = {
        name: 'home'
    }
</script>
```

If I register it locally, it works OK:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <my-component></my-component>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
module.exports = {
    name: 'home',
    components: {
        'my-component': require('./my-component.vue')
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You need to require the component somewhere otherwise it won't be downloaded.

Comment: @Elfayer Everything is within a bundle created by Vueify and the home component is required in the main.js file.

Answer (score 51):

You don't need the module.exports. You can register the component globally by having this within the mycomponent.vue file.

```
<template>
    <div>A custom component!</div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```

Then add to main.js

```
import MyComponent from './component.vue'
Vue.component('my-component', MyComponent);
```

or I typically register them in a 'globals' file them import that into the main.

That should then allow you to use my-component anywhere in the app.

Comment: I use browserify / vueify and ES5. Because of that I have to use _module.export_ and _require_.

Comment: `=` should be removed in `export default = {}`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I spent two days reading the docs and SO to try to understanding how to globally declare a single-page component, while the syntax was simply `Vue.component('my-component', MyComponent);` :)

Comment: Thank you so much man ! can you please tell me whats the difference between both `Vue.component('card', require('./components/card.vue'));` and `import Card from './components/card.vue'; Vue.component('card', Card);` ?

Comment: @PardeepJain both of these statements evaluate to the same thing. The former uses the UMD `require` function, which is an interim solution for including modular Javascript dependencies. The latter uses the modern ES6 `import` standard syntax (tho it's still in it's early days and therefore oft unsupported so any scripts which use the `import` statement will likely need to be transpiled to vanilla `require`-style JS for now.)

Comment: @J.Molinero, From the OP, the first example i.e. without registering locally works in my localhost. So what is the problem coding in that way ?

Answer (score 3):

Component.vue

```
<template><div>A custom component!</div></template>

<script>export default { code here... }</script>
```

Use this component in home.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <my-component></my-component>
    </div>
</template>

 <script>
    import component from './component.vue'
    export default {
     components: { my-component: component }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't want to locally register *my-component*, I wan't to be able to use it all over the app and because of that I want to register it globally using *Vue.component*