# Sending data using props in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Checked most of the questions in and out of stackoverflow about the props in vue however, I'm still struggling on how to apply it on what I'm working.

I have a global component that fetch all the menus. Once fetched, it will construct or build the list (menus):

```
Vue.component('sidenav', require('./components/Sidenav.vue'));
```

**Already did:**

- Add `prop: [menus]` in **customer/index.vue**
- Set **prop to true** in router *(customer)*
- Bind the menu in **Sidenav.vue** : `<input type="hidden" :menus="menus">`

**Need to achieve:**
I want to send the data ("menus") to **customer/index.vue** using props instead of calling an API.

Comment: Are you trying to pass data from a child component to a parent?  If so you can't do that. You will need to create an event that the parent listens for. However, it would be great if you provided an example. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Sending-Messages-to-Parents-with-Events.

Comment: Hi @Culpepper, here's the structure of the files:

layout.blade.php
-> header.vue
-> sidenav.vue
-> content.vue
-> footer.vue

- content.vue contains the <router-view> in which for every click in sidenav, it will be displayed in content.vue

- I need to know how to pass the data from the sidenav to the content that is being loaded..

Comment: possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331896/how-to-use-vuejs-2-global-components-inside-single-file-components ?